# Сокращение путем усечения

Tags: сокращения

Нашел в инете:

> Точка не ставится:
>
> в конце сокращения, если в сокращенном слове выброшена срединная
>    часть, а в конце стоит последняя буква полного слова: г-н, млн, млрд и
>    т. п.
>
> При склонении подобных слов точка также не ставится, если они меняют
>    свою форму путем наращения падежных окончаний (г-на, г-ну, г-ном), и
>    подставляется, если форма слова в косвенных падежах остается прежней
>    (10 млн. человек; 20 млрд. экз. книг), так как в этих случаях
>    последняя буква сокращения уже не является последней буквой слова в
>    полной форме: миллионов, миллиардов.   Правильно: 41 млн человек 42  млн. человек Неправильно: 41 млн. человек 42 млрд человек.

Действительно ли такое правило где-то зафиксировано, или это придумки отдельной редакции?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет причин не доверять достойному сайту "Общее языкознание", предлагающему в электронном варианте не менее солидный труд: http://genling.ru/books/item/f00/s00/z0000026/st000.shtml.

> Мильчин А. Э. Методика и техника редактирования текста. М., "Книга",
>   1972. 320 с.
>
> В книге описаны методические и технические приемы редакторского
>   критического анализа текста: его композиции и рубрикации (системы
>   заголовков), его фактической стороны, логических связей и отношений,
>   языка и стиля, графических средств выразительности; содержатся
>   рекомендации по методике правки текста.
>
> Книга предназначена в качестве практического пособия для всех, кто
>   занимается редакторской работой. Однако для редакторов
>   литературно-художественных произведений она будет полезна лишь
>   отчасти, так как в основном построена на материале литературы не
>   художественной. Несомненный интерес пособие представляет для
>   журналистов, авторов, работников научно-технической информации.

Comment: Мильчин, конечно, авторитет. Но получается, что это ЕГО правило? А есть ли такое правило в правилах русского языка? Нигде не видел, чтобы соблюдали вышеприведенные требования (относительно млн и млрд).

Comment: Исхожу из сказанного: сайт, который выстроен на всём советском языкознании, важнейших словарях, трудах и новостных изданиях, может считаться авторитетным. Если «вышеприведенные требования» не соблюдались кем-то, приведите источник несоблюдения, — только так можно понять проблему. Вполне объяснимо невнимательное прочтение правил, тем более исключений к правилам.

Comment: Таких примеров достаточно много в Нацкорпусе. Например: Неделя. Барометр // «Огонек», 2015 
    1, 1 млн рублей в среднем стоил новый легковой автомобиль в России по итогам прошлого года, подсчитал Автостат.

Comment: Хорошее — это исключение в правилах. Логичное. По этой точке, или её отсутствию, можно понять авторское отношение к таким тонким материям. Или оценить качество работы редактора.